# Web application using Node.js/socket.io and php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, sockets

I am relatively new to node.js and socket.io. Currently I have a half finished private web project, which runs only with PHP with a MySQL database on the server side. I decided to bring it to a more advanced level using socket.io, for several features within the project.

So I read a lot about it and watched a whole bunch of tutorials.  Also I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209717/how-to-integrate-nodejs-socket-io-and-php) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818312/mysql-with-node-js) during my research.

My question is, if that is still the common way to develop a web application?

More exactly: to use on one event (like a form submit) both an AJAX request and a socket.emit, for those events it is necessary/wanted.

The background of this thought is the following. I have a whole bunch of calculations running now in PHP. And the node.js server runs logically in JavaScript. So I can easily implement a node.js server without changing anything on my AJAX requests. Or rewrite everything I have so far, to js and use only a node.js server.

But this leads to 3 more questions:

1. Which runs possibly faster on the server side. A calculation scripted with PHP or JavaScript?
2. How to use transactions on a node.js server while using MySQL?
3. And how great is the influence by converting a PHP array to a JSON object, what you could avoid with the usage of just the node.js server where you don't need to convert anything.

Answer (score 0):

1. JavaScript is executed on the client side so you are limited by the user's hardware whereas PHP is executed on your server. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866738/speed-of-php-vs-javascript) for more info about performance comparaison.
2. I highly suggest you take a look at this [pure node.js client](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) that will perfectly do the job in your case.
3. PHP has many functions to use on JSON data (`json_decode(), json_encode(), ...`) but Node.js don't require JSON data to be converted. In the end, it really depend on your usage and how you plan to store and use that data

Comment: Thanks for your response!
1. but node.js runs on the server right? So u could do calculations with some data u get from the database, and than send it to the client.  

2. Thanks! didnt found that.  

3. I use that already, Thanks. the question was more, if the combination of php and json_encode() is one some point slower as a javascript calculation on the server side.

Comment: In the particular case of node.js yes , you are perfectly right . Also JavaScript calculation should've faster but again , it all depends on your usage .